# Link master/child fields on a sub report where master field is a list of values

Tags: ms-access, vba, subreport

I've got a report recordsource with a text field that contains a list of ids like this:

```
CATEGORY_IDS
----------
1,23,23,16
```

This report has a subreport, and I would like to link master field CATEGORY_IDS with child field CATEGORY_ID with this pseudocode logic:

```
SELECT * FROM SUBRPT_TBL WHERE CATEGORY_ID IN ( RPT_TBL.CATEGORY_IDS )
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: perhaps you need to [JOIN your tables](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing & executing a query to select the applicable data into a [temporary] table, and using that in the subform.

Eg:

```
dim rst as recordset
dim sql as string

set rst = "SELECT CATEGORY_IDS FROM RPT_TBL"
sql = "SELECT s.* INTO TempTableName FROM SubRpt_Tbl s WHERE CATEGORY_ID IN ("
sql = sql & rst!Category_IDs & ")"

docmd.setwarnings false
docmd.runsql sql
docmd.setwarnings true
```

& the sub-reports recordsource is then

```
SELECT * FROM TempTableName
```